# Flutter: Need to hide suggestion/correction text space in iOS keyboard

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I tried `autocorrect: false` and `enableSuggestions: false` codes to hide the suggestion/correction text space in the iOS keyboard. The functions was disabled but the space was can't able to hind

[iOS_Keboard_Space_Hide_Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UGQI.png)

Need to hide the empty space in keyboard

Comment: Can you try with this ```keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword``` .. I can understand that can be hack but just suggesting if you are okay with that

Answer (score 0):

You can try these combinations:

```
  autocorrect: false,
  enableSuggestions: false,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress, // or TextInputType.name
```

If you prefer `TextInputType.name` only the letters and numbers will be available, not the special characters such as - , _ , etc..

Otherwise you can try `emailAddress` enum, which is the closest option to the default keyboard.